# PayPal Express Checkout - Redirect URL

Tags: paypal

I want to set up a recurring payment with PayPal.
But when I want to redirect the user to:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi?bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<value_returned_by_SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
```

I end up at the PayPal.com page, though the correct url is set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the URL, isn't `cgi?bin` supposed to be `cgi-bin`?

Comment: Correct... seems like an error in PayPal documentation. Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's an error in the PayPal documentation at [Integrating Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id086513007E9).
At 'Redirecting the Buyer to PayPal' there url is:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi?bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<value_returned_by_SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
```

When it should be:

```
    https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<value_returned_by_SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
```

Thanks to Jensen Ching for pointing this out.